# Python Threading not processed parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm intermidiate bee for python and would like to run the same class instances of few in parallel mode for fetching data and decision making for financial market. To proceed my idea, I run the following code to see how python works, it seems it works one complete run of first class instance and after second class instances, I would like to run this parallely, how can I...?
Below is the some sample code for testing..

```
import threading
import time

class thr(object):

  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
     self.x = 0

  def run(self):
     for i in list(range(10)):
         self.x +=1
         print("something {0} {1}".format(self.name, self.x))
         time.sleep(1)            

F = thr("First")
S = thr("Second")

threading.Thread(target=F.run())
threading.Thread(target=S.run())
```

and the results as below....

```
something First 1
something First 2
something First 3
something First 4
something First 5
something First 6
something First 7
something First 8
something First 9
something First 10
something Second 1
something Second 2
something Second 3
something Second 4
something Second 5
something Second 6
something Second 7
something Second 8
something Second 9
something Second 10
Out[27]: <Thread(Thread-25, initial)>
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is here:

```
threading.Thread(target=F.run())
threading.Thread(target=S.run())
```

`target=` takes a callable object or `None`.  `F.run()` *executes* `F.run` immediately, waits for it finish, and then passes the return value (which is `None` in your `run()` method) as the target.

You want something like this instead:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=F.run)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=S.run)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Note that there's no parentheses after `run`

Here's the complete program with the suggested change:

```
import threading
import time

class thr(object):

  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
     self.x = 0

  def run(self):
     for i in list(range(10)):
         self.x +=1
         print("something {0} {1}".format(self.name, self.x))
         time.sleep(1)            

F = thr("First")
S = thr("Second")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=F.run)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=S.run)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

And output (Python 3.6.1):

```
$ python sf.py
something First 1
something Second 1
something Second 2
something First 2
something Second 3
something First 3
something Second 4
something First 4
something Second 5
something First 5
something Second 6
something First 6
something Second 7
something First 7
something First 8
something Second 8
something First 9
something Second 9
something First 10
something Second 10
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted this:  make the change I suggested, and actually run the code.  It solves the OP's stated problem, and for exactly the reason I gave.

Comment: Yes, it is - but, unfortunately, anyone can vote ;-)

Comment: They must not know uncle Timmy :-)

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work. If you're really confident I can take that back, but I cannot see what I could have done wrong while trying it. Unfortunately I cannot take back the vote until you've edited the answer.

Comment: OK, I posted the complete program with the suggested change, and sample output from one run.  If it doesn't work for you, please supply an equivalent level of detail so people don't have to guess what "did not work" means.

Comment: Well, what I thought I did was taking OP:s code and did the changes you proposed and run the code with `python3 p.py` but it did not work. Now when I copied everything you posted it does work. I have honestly no clue at all what went wrong. Vote changed.

Comment: And by "did not work" I meant that I got exactly the same result as OP got.

Comment: Perhaps you left the parentheses in?  It's _crucial_ that, e.g., `F.run()` be changed to `F.run`.  Otherwise (as explained in the answer), `F.run` is run to completion, and `None` is passed to `target=`.  As not explained in the answer, if `None` _is_ passed as the target, `Thread.start()` doesn't do anything - it doesn't run anything, and neither does it raise an exception.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for enlightening me.